# what is difference between ajaxComplete and beforesend in Ajax calling using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can i use `ajaxComplete` and `beforesend` ? ,
what are the main differences between them? and what are other methods available like this except `success` in `Ajax` calling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/)  Register a handler to be called when Ajax requests complete.

**beforesend**  : A pre-request callback function that can be used to modify the jqXHR object before it is sent. Use this to set custom headers, etc. The jqXHR and settings objects are passed as arguments. This is an Ajax Event. Returning false in the beforeSend function will cancel the reques

you can read more  [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

ON this **[Link](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)** you can find all other methods related [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)

Comment: is there any other methods like this?

Comment: @ThamaraiselvamThangavel  check this link  http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/   all jquery ajax methods are listed